# Tensorflow Eager Execution Multithreaded

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Running a DDPG reinforcement learner on tensorflow 2.0. The training is pretty slow for the batch size I'm using, so I'm looking to run the training in a separate thread than the execution.

However, when trying to train the Tensorflow model on a separate thread than I use it to predict and execute I run into problems.

First there's the graph error:

> ValueError: Tensor("dense_2/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp:0", shape=(3, 9), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Const:0", shape=(32, 3), dtype=float32).

This one is pretty easy to resolve by restoring the graph from the primary thread on the training thread:

```
with self.tf_graph.as_default():
```

This error then goes away, but on the new thread eager execution is disabled, and this causes other problems. Is there a way to restore the session of the tensorflow model on the second thread so that the tensorflow model can be trained on one thread and evaluated on a different one? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got this working. I was running tensorflow 1.4 when I thought I was using tensorflow 2 and thus eager execution was disabled by default. Once I enabled eager execution I didn't need to do anything special on the other thread, it just worked.

I created a separate copy of the model on the main thread, and copied the weights from the training thread in a lock right before execution.